# Gunicorn not found in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, deployment, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm deploying a django application and it works fine when I run it manually. I'm trying to use supervisor but when I run sudo supervisorctl status botApp the log file says:

```
Starting botApp as ubuntu
/home/ubuntu/gunicorn_start.bash: line 28: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

My gunicorn_start.bash is the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="botApp"                                   # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/chimpy               # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/django_env/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=ubuntu                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=botApp.settings      # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=botApp.wsgi              # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

And my configuration file in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/botApp.conf is:

```
[program:botApp]
command = /home/ubuntu/gunicorn_start.bash;
user = ubuntu;
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log;
redirect_stderr = true;
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
```

Is something wrong in my gunicorn bash? Many thanks

Comment: Silly question, but did you install gunicorn via `pip install gunicorn`?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac yes, I can run the gunicorn_start.bash manually and it works apparently fine

Comment: If you use `/home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/gunicorn` instead of `gunicorn` in the bash script, then you shouldn't need the `source` command to activate the virtual environment.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm sorry Alasdair I'm completely new to gunicorn, should I delete the line with source and replace gunicorn with "/home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/gunicorn" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: It worked, thank you! (again :) )

Answer (score 1):

To check virtual environment is active or not. Just write the simple script

```
#!bin/bash

source /var/www/html/project_env/bin/activate
```

Then run command 
-> sudo bash file_name.sh

If you will not get any error  that mean venv is activated

**Note** - You will not get any venv activate mark on terminal or shell.